# The effects of the `!important` tag in CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

In CSS, there's an hierarchy of developing stylesheets: the web-page developer writes a stylesheet, the reader writes another one, and then there's the default stylesheet of the browser. It is known that the order of precedence for the application of the stylesheets are: the developer's, the reader's and the browser's.

It is also known, however, that the reader can override a style assigned by the developer by appending `!important` to the property declaration:

```
h1 {
color: white !important;
}
```

However, what happens if the developer, too, appends `!important` at the end of their property declaration. Which one takes precedence in this case? Also, does the browser's stylesheet have any `!important` appended to any property declaration? If it does, how does this effect the style of the web-page?

The book I use for studying HTML and CSS, *Head First HTML and CSS, 2nd edition by O'Reilly*, tells me there's nothing I can do to override the reader's style (or atleast, that's what I've inferred—it may be that I've misunderstood). I did not try fiddling with the 'reader's' stylesheet simply because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The last !important rule is the one that will be applied

Comment: If two rules affecting an element both include an `!important` flag, it should fall back to standard [specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception), not necessarily the last `!important`. (There's a bit more to it, read the docs link)

Comment: Since this has changed a bit over the years, I recommend learning [the modern cascade](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade-5/#cascade-sort). For !important declarations though, user-agent origin beats reader origin, which beats author origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned you are referring `Head First HTML and CSS, 2nd edition by O'Reilly`, it is important to note it is released in **2012**.and over the year `!important` rules have changed.

I would suggest you go through certian articles.

- As @DBS suggested in the comment,

  > If two rules affecting an element both include an `!important` flag, it should fall back to standard [specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception), not necessarily the last `!important`
- Followed by this [article](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/css-important)

  > By default, CSS rules in an author's stylesheet override those in a user's stylesheet. However, to create a balance of power between authors and users, !important rules in a user stylesheet will override !important rules in the author’s stylesheet. This CSS feature is designed for accessibility. Users that need larger fonts, specific color combinations, or other requirements due to disabilities related to vision can maintain control over the presentation of a web page.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, the answer helped a lot. I do understand that the book's quite old, so I may not be caught up with some rules. Can you tell me where I can look for the ones developed after 2012? For instance, how about MDN Web Docs?

Comment: Yes MDN Web Docs is the perfect place to keep yourself updated with the rules , even in the future , it's well maintained